# Max Child Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I cannot find an answer to this (Maybe because I am approaching it the wrong way).

Is there a limit to how many child and nested child windows you can have?

I want to create child windows to represent an object that will be sub-divided into smaller parts and represent those within their respective parent.

e.g. a piece of wood 2700 mm long with cut pieces allocated to it of various lengths.  I can draw them with GDI but I want them interactive for editing so thought windows would be a good option. Perhaps like this...
[image: Example of final view]

I anticipate up to 50 child and another 5 sub child windows per project, so 250 child and sub child windows, and that does not include Main window and other controls.

Any advice welcome.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you observe some unsatisfactory behavior, when trying it, that led you to this conclusion?

Comment: When child window is created the parent window receives WM_PARENTNOTIFY message
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/inputmsg/wm-parentnotify
You can use that message to destroy the windows when created. Use EnumChildWindows to find their count.

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-8211-part-1/ba-p/723881

Comment: A basic limitation imposed by the window manager is that no process can create more than 10,000 USER objects.

Comment: Thanks both of you.  No I didn't try it, my question was more based on theoretical understanding.  I can for sure create many levels of Child window but was curious to know the limits, if any.

Comment: One window per log piece is certainly a bad idea. Typically it should be one window per widget. So you should make a collection window, conceptually similar to list view. One window for displaying collection of objects that is.

Comment: 250 child windows is likely not going to be anywhere near any of the limits you might bump into. It's questionable, though, whether this makes the UI easier to render, manage, or interact with. Implementing a single custom window per wood piece is a likely to produce a much more robust solution, that's also a lot easier to maintain as the project changes over time. One example to illustrate this: With a single window you only have to maintain a single scale for rendering, as opposed to ensuring that all child windows share the same scale.

Comment: @cgts There seems no official document states this kind of limit. Based on my test, at least, 250 is not the limit. What do you mean by *interactive for editing*?  Could you show more specified information about this?